# What is the best way to handle numbers with - and . with a controlled input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to save the input in number type every time the value updates. However, with this approach, The value is stuck in NaN or 0 in the scenarios below.

scenario 1: changing 0 to 0.1 (stuck in 0 when '0.' left)

scenario 2: changing -15 to 1 (stuck in NaN when only '-' left)

What would be the best way to handle these cases when 1) the input has to be controlled element and 2) storing value in string format is not an option?

```js
export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <input value={input} onChange={(e)=>setInput(parseFloat(e.target.value))}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: make it input type number

Comment: Please explain the question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check before setting the state to see if the input value is parsable to a float.

```js
function checkSetInput(e) {

  const val = parseFloat(e.target.value);

  if (isNaN(val)) 
    return // do not set state when the input is not parsable

  setInput(val); // otherwise do set the state

}

...

<input value={input} onChange={checkSetInput} />
```